# Navigation Bar pushed out of safe area when TextField is Selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I made a viewController that I present modally using the following code:

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {

            destination.post = (posts[indexPath.row])
            destination.delegate = self
            present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
```

And I have the constraint that the top of the Navigation Bar is aligned to the top of the safe area.

When I select the textField, the done button bar appears, pushing the Navigation Bar out of the safe area.

View controller before selecting text field:

[image: View Controller Before Selecting Text Field]

View controller after selecting text field:
[image: View Controller After Selecting Text Field]

Note: I'm using IQKeyBoardManager:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

I can disable the IQKeyBoardManager, but then the keyboard will cover the textView

How do you fix this issue and keep the Navigation Bar locked inside the safe area?

Comment: What keyboard notification code are you using?

Comment: Have you written any code for moving the views when keyboard appears?

Comment: I'm using IQKeyBoardManager: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Okay so let’s get this straight. You are using third party code. It’s broken. You refuse to stop using it (“I can disable the IQKeyBoardManager, but then the keyboard will cover the textView”).  What’s the question? To put it another way, why not write your own code to prevent the keyboard from covering the text view, and do it correctly?

Comment: That's what I am doing right now matt. Haven't figured out the solution yet though.